# How to sort a list with a custom key using the Python C API?

Tags: python, python-c-api

The Python C API provides the follow method for sorting lists:

> `int PyList_Sort(PyObject *list)`
>
> Sort the items of list in place.
>   Return `0` on success, `-1` on failure. This is equivalent to `list.sort()`.

However, no argument is available for providing a custom sort key (as there is for `list.sort()` in Python).  What is the best way to sort a Python list in C with a custom key?

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick:

```
static PyObject *sortWithKey(PyObject *list, PyObject *key) {
    PyObject *argTuple = PyTuple_New(0);
    PyObject *keywords = PyDict_New();
    PyObject *keyString = PyUnicode_FromString("key");
    PyDict_SetItem(keywords, keyString, key);

    PyObject *sortMethod = PyObject_GetAttrString(list, "sort");

    PyObject *retVal = PyObject_Call(sortMethod, argTuple, keywords);

    Py_DECREF(keyString);
    Py_DECREF(keywords);
    Py_DECREF(argTuple);

    return retVal;
}
```

Beware that I am very new at writing Python modules, so the memory management/exception handling here may not be a good model.